# Error using "python -m twisted.conch.stdio" command in command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt, twisted, twisted.conch

I'm trying to use the "python -m twisted.conch.stdio" command in command prompt but it does not work and gives the following error:

```html
C:\Users\Melanie>python -m twisted.conch.stdio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Melanie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\twisted\conch\stdio.py", line 11, in <module>
    import os, tty, sys, termios
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
```

**I want to eventually be ably to run :**

```html
>>> from twisted.names import client
>>> client.getHostByName('www.example.com')
<Deferred at 0xf5c5a8 waiting on Deferred at 0xf5cb90>
>>> _
<Deferred at 0xf5c5a8 current result: '2606:2800:220:6d:26bf:1447:1097:aa7'>

>>> client.lookupMailExchange('twistedmatrix.com')
<Deferred at 0xf5cd40 waiting on Deferred at 0xf5cea8>
>>> _
<Deferred at 0xf5cd40 current result: ([<RR name=twistedmatrix.com type=MX class=IN ttl=1s auth=False>], [], [])>
```

**The aim is to get the deferred responses as shown in previous code, but all I get is:**

```html
>>> from twisted.names import client
>>> client.getHostByName('www.example.com')
<Deferred at 0x263d27b9dc8 waiting on Deferred at 0x263d27b9f48>
>>> _
<Deferred at 0x263d27b9dc8 waiting on Deferred at 0x263d27b9f48>
>>> client.lookupMailExchange('twistedmatrix.com')
<Deferred at 0x263d27c6a88 waiting on Deferred at 0x263d27c6c08>
>>> _
<Deferred at 0x263d27c6a88 waiting on Deferred at 0x263d27c6c08>
```

Please help.

Kind regards

M

Comment: It seems there is `No module named 'termios'`.
Have you tried to run `pip install termios` ?

Comment: Cross-reference: [This question was asked and answered on the Twisted mailing list](https://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2021-July/065676.html).

Comment: @lucascavalcante, thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion. It doesn't do anything. I just get the reply: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement termios (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for termios. I tried different variations to it too, related to Twisted framework. Nothing.